# planar graph- combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let n be the the number of points in a plane so there are no 3 points in the same straight line.
 **d** is the minimal distance between any distinct pair of points in the plane.
 I need to prove that there are at least **n/4** points, that their minimal distance is greater than d.
I tried to depict a graph with n vertices so that there are edges between u and v if and only if the distance between them is d, without succeeding.